# Writer is not working after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04 and Libreoffice writer does not work.
Opens no old files, and cannot create new files. LibreOffice closed. Calc seems to work. I had this problem on another system, too.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run LibreOffice Writer using this command? libreoffice --writer

Comment: Maybe Libreoffice is buggy. I suggest you to reinstall it: `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice libreoffice-writer libreoffice-core`

Comment: NO error: Libreoffice is closing after trying to open or creating a file.
Twice on two different pc